# Apple watch and iPhone are not connected when the app in phone goes to background

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I ran my iPhone app and its watch extension in the simulator. I send messages from phone to watch and vice versa. The messages are sent and received without any issue. But when I send the iPhone app to background, and then a message is sent from watch to iPhone, I continuously get the following log:

> [WC] __33-[WCXPCManager onqueue_reconnect]_block_invoke error reconnecting to daemon due to NSXPCConnectionInterrupted

I searched regarding this but did not find any proper solution. Many have posted it as an issue in the betas of Xcode. I am using the latest Xcode 8.1. What could be the proper solution?

Comment: Can you give samples of code that you are using for sending in background to clarify your problem.