# Where Can I Intercept NSXPCConnectionInterrupted?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos, watchos-3

OK. I have an app that is in regular communication with a Watch.

They are running apps that can do iOS 10.0 or greater, and WatchOS 3.0 or greater. I don't care about less.

When the iOS app gets shoved into the background, comms to the Watch get interrupted, and I start seeing log entries that mention NSXPCConnectionInterrupted, which is a standard Foundation error.

I have a couple of issues:

1) Where can I intercept this error? It doesn't seem to be showing up in my callbacks or delegate methods.

2) This is not a question. It's just an annoyance. In the simulator, I don't get this. It only happens in the device itself. I didn't encounter it until I was at a point where I could actually install and run on-device.

Comment: It is possible to get this error in the Simulator as well, I got it when I only ran the iOS app from Xcode, but didn't start the Watch app manually. [Someone else has also reported your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756505/apple-watch-and-iphone-are-not-connected-when-the-app-in-phone-goes-to-backgroun), but no answers so far for that question either.

Comment: I'm not trying to intercept it. I'm seeing if I can somehow set and maintain a connection state in the Watch app. If the connection is good, the Watch app runs fine. If bad, then it should just refuse to operate. The phone app can work fine without the Watch app, but not the other way round.